# Creating a user and granting all privileges on mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database on mySQL and I keep getting a syntax error when trying to create a user and grant all privileges.

```
 create database name
          -> grant all privileges on name.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by '1234';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

I feel like I've typed this out exactly as the book tells me to but I'm getting a syntax error. I tried following a different guide at https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-mysql-user-accounts-and-grant-privileges/ and I also got a syntax error.

```
create database bank
      -> CREATE USER 'useraccount'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xyz'
      -> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON bank.* TO 'useraccount'@'localhost';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

Would anyone be able to help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to terminate the `CREATE USER` statement using `;`

Comment: And the database creation has to be terminated as well. Otherwise this would be treated as one single command that is not syntactical correct.

Comment: So I do each of the lines one by one and add ; it should work? After doing 'create database name' I got Query OK, 1 row affected and then for the others I got 0 rows affected. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this should be it.